# use coloured vector image in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I want to use Colored svg images on my apps footer, but I am getting two problems:-

1. I am able to use the images but only after I make a xml through "Image asset" option. When I apply that image the color is changed to black,the text written in the image is not supported and sometimes it is also auto-filled in some areas.
2. I tried implementing an api "caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1" it gave an error in its own caverock custom Imageview and then become useless.
3. I got some jar file as well "svg-android-1.1.jar" through this thread [How to use SVG image in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923205/easiest-way-to-use-svg-in-android) but my footer in a xml which has no java file so i am not sure how to implement the code.
4. If they are not svg. Please tell me what they are and how can I start.

The current  images that I am using in application are png which get pixelated, all I need is some sharp icons which can enhance the look and feel of my home screen.

An ideal reference is the PayTm app's home screen (attached with this question). Please suggest something.

Thank you for your time I need the icons like in this image which I can use in my android application

[image]

Comment: you can use color svg simply. I'm using in my application.. just download svg icon and right click on `drawable>new>vector asset`. and import that svg. and put it to your image view as `android:src`. you don't need to use any library for that

Comment: @AbhishekSingh  thank you for your reply i tried the same thing I have a normal smiley image in svg (made by a designer) when i import it it fills the whole circle and removes the text in the importing window only then shows the same thing while executing.

Comment: post your svg file so that I can try and check what the real problem

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B98IbtbtNtLdaFJRdVNMNjVoZVk?usp=sharing)

Image 1 is the screen shot for when i import image, smiling is the svg file i am trying to implement.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I have posted the svg file please have a look.

Comment: check my answer. will be helpfull for you. your designer need to create svg more correctly

Comment: @AbhishekSingh It worked..Thank you so much Abhishek..for your help...you are a life saver..can you please tell me what did you do correctly while creating the image so that i can tell the designer as well. He designed this image through Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Your designer took white board to draw image. it should be transparent board or some shape (if background needed) as board with fill color. I don't know much about Adobe Illustrator. So I give your image to my designer he done this. he used Adobe Illustrator. so main concept is no background if an background needed the use some shape with fill color as path

Comment: @AbhishekSingh ok i have shared this post with the designer he is working on it . Thank you so much abhishek once again for your help. Thanks a ton.

Comment: enjoy coding :)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Hi Abhishek ,me and my designer both tried to create that image but we are nowhere (we also tried the white/transparent board but still it din't worked) , can you please give us a lead so that we can move atleat a step ahead..

Comment: bro I just opened your svg in illustrator and pressed ctrl+shift+D to make is transparent and saved again after that file is working

Comment: Thank you @AbhishekSingh and the Designer guy the problem still remains as my designer has tried many solutions but we are not able to generate a proper image as it still gets modify after i import it through my ide..

Comment: you can share your svg . may be i can recreate for u

Comment: @AbhishekSingh thanks for your help but we have many icons we might consider some other plan (may be creating multiple SVGs)..But still thank you very much for your help....it was nice talking to you..

Comment: you can create png image of same image with size of `48 × 48 (mdpi) 72 × 72 (hdpi) 96 × 96 (xhdpi) 144 × 144 (xxhdpi) 192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)` it will auto adjust like svg. you can refer this link to understand [drawables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517389/android-understanding-drawable-folder)

Comment: @AbhishekSingh i applied multiple pngs with the same dimensions its working great thanks a lot for your help it almost like svg only...Thanks a ton for your time :)...

And designer friend as well thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your Svg and there is somthing wrong in your svg. So I recreated svg and imported in my drawable. use this xml directly as drawable. its generated by SVG

> ic_smile_new.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="256.0"
    android:viewportWidth="256.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M125.3,159.6C82.68,159.6 48,124.92 48,82.3C48,39.68 82.68,5 125.3,5s77.3,34.68 77.3,77.3C202.6,124.92 167.92,159.6 125.3,159.6zM125.3,6C83.23,6 49,40.23 49,82.3c0,42.07 34.23,76.3 76.3,76.3c42.07,0 76.3,-34.23 76.3,-76.3C201.6,40.23 167.37,6 125.3,6z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M102.11,55.73m-12.07,0a12.07,12.07 0,1 1,24.15 0a12.07,12.07 0,1 1,-24.15 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M158.63,58.63m-12.07,0a12.07,12.07 0,1 1,24.15 0a12.07,12.07 0,1 1,-24.15 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M161.32,109.66c-19.32,19.8 -50.23,19.32 -69.07,-0.48c-2.9,-2.9 -7.24,1.45 -4.35,4.35c21.25,22.22 56.51,22.22 77.77,0.48C168.57,111.11 164.22,106.76 161.32,109.66L161.32,109.66z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M183.26,48.97h-1.93c-2.41,-6.76 -10.63,-7.24 -20.29,-7.24c-1.45,0 -2.9,0 -3.86,0c-1.45,0 -2.9,0 -3.87,0c-9.66,0 -17.87,0.48 -20.29,7.24h-8.69c-2.41,-6.76 -10.63,-7.24 -20.29,-7.24c-1.45,0 -2.9,0 -3.86,0c-1.45,0 -2.9,0 -3.86,0c-9.66,0 -17.87,0.48 -20.29,7.24H74.1c-2.9,0 -5.31,2.41 -5.31,5.31c0,2.9 2.41,5.31 5.31,5.31h1.45c2.42,11.59 12.56,20.29 24.63,20.29c12.07,0 22.7,-8.69 24.63,-20.29h7.73c2.42,11.59 12.56,20.29 24.64,20.29c12.07,0 22.7,-8.69 24.63,-20.29h1.45c2.9,0 5.31,-2.41 5.31,-5.31C188.58,51.39 186.16,48.97 183.26,48.97zM111.29,67.33H88.11c-0.48,0 -1.45,0 -1.93,-2.9h26.57C112.26,67.33 111.78,67.33 111.29,67.33zM91.49,70.22h15.46c-2.41,0 -4.83,1.93 -7.73,1.93C96.32,72.16 93.9,70.22 91.49,70.22zM115.16,62.01H83.28c-0.48,-2.9 -0.48,-1.93 -0.48,-2.9h33.33C115.64,60.08 115.64,59.6 115.16,62.01zM168.29,67.33h-23.19c-0.48,0 -1.45,0 -1.93,-2.9h26.57C169.74,67.33 169.26,67.33 168.29,67.33zM148.97,70.22h15.46c-2.41,0 -4.83,1.93 -7.73,1.93C154.28,72.16 151.38,70.22 148.97,70.22zM172.64,62.01h-31.88c-0.48,-2.9 -0.48,-1.93 -0.48,-2.9h33.33C173.12,60.08 173.12,59.6 172.64,62.01z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M143.65,63.94h-7.73V56.7h7.73V63.94zM136.89,62.98h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V62.98z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M147.04,70.22h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V70.22zM139.79,69.26h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V69.26z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M155.73,75.54h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V75.54zM148.48,75.06h6.28v-5.8h-6.28C148.48,68.78 148.48,75.06 148.48,75.06z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M166.36,75.54h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V75.54zM159.11,75.06h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V75.06z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M173.12,69.74h-7.73v-7.25h7.73V69.74zM165.87,68.78h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V68.78z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M176.98,63.46h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V63.46zM169.74,62.98h6.28V56.7h-6.28V62.98z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M86.18,63.94h-7.73V56.7h7.73V63.94zM78.93,62.98h6.28v-5.8H78.93V62.98z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M89.56,70.22h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V70.22zM82.31,69.26h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V69.26z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M97.77,75.54H90.04v-7.24h7.73V75.54zM91.01,75.06h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V75.06z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M108.88,75.54h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V75.54zM101.63,75.06h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V75.06z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M115.64,69.74h-7.73v-7.25h7.73V69.74zM108.39,68.78h6.28v-5.8h-6.28V68.78z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#F6BE19" android:pathData="M119.5,63.46h-7.73v-7.24h7.73V63.46zM112.26,62.98h6.28V56.7h-6.28V62.98z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M59.64,173.34h5.88v40.64H85v4.94h-25.36V173.34z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M120.03,202.28c0,12.1 -8.39,17.38 -16.3,17.38c-8.86,0 -15.69,-6.49 -15.69,-16.84c0,-10.95 7.17,-17.38 16.23,-17.38C113.67,185.44 120.03,192.27 120.03,202.28zM94.06,202.62c0,7.17 4.13,12.58 9.94,12.58c5.68,0 9.94,-5.34 9.94,-12.71c0,-5.55 -2.77,-12.58 -9.81,-12.58S94.06,196.4 94.06,202.62z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M155.73,186.19c-0.14,2.37 -0.27,5.01 -0.27,8.99v19c0,7.51 -1.49,12.1 -4.67,14.94c-3.18,2.98 -7.78,3.92 -11.9,3.92c-3.92,0 -8.25,-0.94 -10.89,-2.7l1.49,-4.53c2.16,1.35 5.55,2.57 9.6,2.57c6.09,0 10.55,-3.18 10.55,-11.43v-3.65h-0.14c-1.83,3.04 -5.34,5.48 -10.41,5.48c-8.11,0 -13.93,-6.9 -13.93,-15.96c0,-11.09 7.24,-17.38 14.74,-17.38c5.68,0 8.79,2.98 10.21,5.68h0.14l0.27,-4.94H155.73zM149.58,199.1c0,-1.02 -0.07,-1.89 -0.34,-2.7c-1.08,-3.45 -3.99,-6.29 -8.32,-6.29c-5.68,0 -9.74,4.8 -9.74,12.38c0,6.42 3.25,11.77 9.67,11.77c3.65,0 6.97,-2.3 8.25,-6.09c0.34,-1.01 0.47,-2.16 0.47,-3.18V199.1z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M171.55,176.99c0.07,2.03 -1.42,3.65 -3.79,3.65c-2.1,0 -3.59,-1.62 -3.59,-3.65c0,-2.1 1.56,-3.72 3.72,-3.72C170.13,173.27 171.55,174.89 171.55,176.99zM164.93,218.92v-32.73h5.95v32.73H164.93z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#2A2853" android:pathData="M180.75,195.04c0,-3.38 -0.07,-6.15 -0.27,-8.86h5.28l0.34,5.41h0.14c1.62,-3.11 5.41,-6.15 10.82,-6.15c4.53,0 11.56,2.7 11.56,13.93v19.55h-5.95v-18.87c0,-5.27 -1.96,-9.67 -7.57,-9.67c-3.92,0 -6.97,2.77 -7.98,6.09c-0.27,0.74 -0.41,1.76 -0.41,2.77v19.68h-5.95V195.04z"/>
</vector>
```