# How to load images for different densities from server

Tags: android, json, image, screen, drawable

I have an `expandableListView` in my activity and passing data from JSON that I get from server. Everything is working fine Except the image part.
I'm getting image path as string within `JSON` for different sizes (`48x48`, `72x72`, `96x96` etc.) but unable to figure out how to assign image according to the screen density. I think I can Add these images into the corresponding drawable folder and android would do the rest. But on searching I did not find any example on how to add images in drawable folder dynamically.

If there is any way to add images dynamically into drawable folder please let me know **OR** suggest any other appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add images dynamically into the drawable folders.

But you can [get the device's screen density programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android). You can use that value in your api and return appropriate image(s).

Answer (score 0):

You must understand whats `drawables` in android by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10517389/1830228)

and you must know that you can't put any images into them dynamically, icons and static images must be into `drawables` folders, for other images which you are using them into application you can get image and thumbnail

Comment: link is blank please add a url to it.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to save in **drawable** at runtime.
you can't use **assets** folder too.

if I were you it I didn't bother my self to determine screen density. use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in order to load image asynchronously.

**Update :** 
the thing that i should mention is that, if the ImaveView is a fixed size view by `dp`  it'll appear "the same size" on all devices as per Android's specs.
glide and Picasso read the view size by pixel and then scale the image to that size.

I prefer Glide because it has a smaller memory footprint by making some different assumptions like caching the resized images instead of the full-sized images.

**Edit:**
 
@greenapps you are completely right. it cannot be saved in **assets** too. try to create a directory and save drawable into that

Comment: I'm using [https://amitshekhariitbhu.github.io/Fast-Android-Networking/loading_image_into_imageview.html#loading-image-from-network-into-imageview] that provide similar feature too but its not good to load same size image for all screen density.

Comment: Do these libraries scale image according to density automatically?

Comment: `it's not possible to save in drawable at runtime. you can use asset folder instead.` No. You cant either. Read only too.